Calling Matlab from Python--can't find database entry
I have a Python script that loads a database and a  series of vectors in Matlab and then runs the vectors through a Matlab script to search for the entries in the database, using matlab.engine. I should note that I didn't write this code (it's from another research team), so I don't have a deep understanding of its inner workings.
The vectors look like this:
'O2  ','N2 ','H2O ','CO2 ','NH3  ','CH4 ','CO ','H2 ','H2S '
0.0000002 0.5 0.02 0.47 0.000000001 0.01 0.001 0.0001 3.13e-5

The database looks like this:
...
H2  33.19   1.313   -0.216
H2O 647.096 22.064  0.3449
H2O2    730.155 21.7    .358233
H2S 373.53  8.963   0.0942
H3N 405.65  11.28   0.2526
NH3 405.65  11.28   0.2526
H4N2    653.15  14.7    0.3143
HCN 456.65  5.39    0.4099
HNO3    520 6.8901  .714406
He  5.2 0.2275  -0.39
NO  180.15  6.48    0.5829
NO2 431.15  10.1325 .851088
N2  126.2   3.4 0.0377
N2O 309.57  7.245   0.1409
Ne  44.4    2.653   -0.0396
O2  154.58  5.043   0.0222
...

And the code to search through the database looks like this:
    
    q = size(n);
    if q(1)>q(2)
        n=n';
    end
    
    for q = 1:length(names)                  % For each species passed.
        index(q) = searchDataB(names(q));    % Get the index in the database of the species
    
        if index(q) == -1                    % If the species isn't there, throw an exception.
            throw(MException('Catling:missingSpecies',['Species ' names{q} ' is missing from the database.']))
        end
        %disp(['Using species: ' names(q)])   % Display which species are being used.

Where names is the vector of chemical names and n is the vector of abundances of the corresponding chemicals.
However, when I run this code via calling it from Python, I get the error message
Species N2  is missing from the database.

Error in Gibbs_energy_minimization>totalGibbsInternal (line 137)
    lnPhi = fugCoef(T,P,onlyPhase(1,names),onlyPhase(1,n'));

Error in Gibbs_energy_minimization (line 69)
    G1=totalGibbsInternal(n_true); % Calculate the total Gibbs energy of the true initial state.

Error in Main_script_iterate (line 27)
        vals=[vals; n Gibbs_energy_minimization(n')]; % run the Gibbs energy minimization routine and store the output in the vals array

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tessa/Alien Earths/phi_calc/phi calc.py", line 181, in <module>
    phi=eng.Main_script_iterate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/matlab/engine/matlabengine.py", line 71, in __call__
    _stderr, feval=True).result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/matlab/engine/futureresult.py", line 62, in result
    return self.__future.result(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/matlab/engine/fevalfuture.py", line 76, in result
    self._result = pythonengine.getFEvalResult(self._future,self._nargout, None, out=self._out, err=self._err)
matlab.engine.MatlabExecutionError: 
  File /home/tessa/Alien Earths/phi_calc/Multiphase_disequilibrium/fugCoef.m, line 32, in fugCoef

  File /home/tessa/Alien Earths/phi_calc/Multiphase_disequilibrium/Gibbs_energy_minimization.m, line 137, in totalGibbsInternal

  File /home/tessa/Alien Earths/phi_calc/Multiphase_disequilibrium/Gibbs_energy_minimization.m, line 69, in Gibbs_energy_minimization

  File /home/tessa/Alien Earths/phi_calc/Multiphase_disequilibrium/Main_script_iterate.m, line 27, in Main_script_iterate
Species N2  is missing from the database.

The only chemicals in the names vector are that don't produce this error are 'O2  ' and 'H2O '. The same thing happens when I run this part of the script directly in Matlab, without Matlab, on my PC (running Linux Mint). However, when I run the Matlab script on Matlab online, however, this part works fine, which makes me wonder if there's some sort of conflict between Matlab and Linux Mint.
Any idea why the script isn't able to find these specific chemicals in the database?

Hard to check what goes wrong here, probably has something to do with the formatting of the names that are in the databases and in the vector? Check if they are the same, maybe trailing spaces or case sensitivity could be the issue. Hard to say, as the only thing I can go on is that the searchDataB function returns -1, because it did not find the name in the database.

If this works if you run it in MATLAB, but doesn’t if you call MATLAB from within Python, then the issue is likely your Python code. Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly.

Unfortunately, it doesn't even work if I don't use the Python code and run it directly through MATLAB. The only way it works is via MATLAB Online.
